# Display lines when the digits repeated in same line

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

I would like to display the lines on text if 3 digits repeated in same line

with a condition applied for 3 digits repeat.

**Input**

```
410202410
203103903
555710294473555
```

so `410` and `555` repeated

**Output**

```
410202410
555710294473555
```

how to handle this through `sed` or `awk`?

I would like also to apply the same only on digits before first comma.

such as `410202410,11,2017,109`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
grep '\([0-9]\{3\}\).*\1'
```

Would print the lines that contain 3 decimal digits followed by a sequence of 0 or more characters followed by the same 3 digits.

To restrict that pattern before the first comma:

```
grep '^[^,]*\([0-9]\{3\}\)[^,]*\1'
```